# Yum repository throwing - [Errno -1] Package does not match intended download

Tags: yum, rpm, repository, packaging

I am building a Yum repository to install RPM packages.

I am creating a folder `mkdir -p ~/yum/el7/x86_64` and moving rpm file to it under same path given above.

#### Here is my my-app.repo file info.

```
[my-app]
name=My App
baseurl=https://dl.my-app.com/yum/el7/$basearch
gpgkey=https://dl.my-app.com/rpm.gpg
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
```

#### Here is the error I get when I install the package.

```
[root@ip-192-31-59-132 ~]# yum install my-app
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package my-app.x86_64 0:1.3.15-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                      Arch                                 Version                                     Repository                                    Size
==================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 my-app                                      x86_64                             1.3.15-2.el7                                my-app                                     9.5 M

Transaction Summary
==================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 9.5 M
Installed size: 33 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
my-app-1.3.15-2.el7.x8 FAILED                                          
https://dl.my-app.com/yum/el7/x86_64/my-app-1.3.15-2.el7.x86_64.rpm: [Errno -1] Package does not match intended download. Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=my-app clean metadata
Trying other mirror.


Error downloading packages:
  my-app-1.3.15-2.el7.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

[root@ip-192-31-59-132 ~]#
```

I have the Gnupg configuration correct. I hope thats not the cause of this issue.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is Yum throwing `Package does not match intended download` error?

Comment: Did you you as suggested: `Suggestion: run yum --enablerepo=my-app clean metadata`.

Comment: Yes. I did that. I even deleted /var/cache/yum

Comment: This seems to be an issue with meta-data

Answer (score 0):

```
# yum clean metadata
```

and try again.  Your client yum(8) has its own idea of the RPM characteristics, so ask it to check their repo value again.

Comment: I have tried this and `yum clean all`. Its something to do with metadata

Comment: There is something wrong with the package name too. Its show half of it `my-app-1.3.15-2.el7.x8`

Comment: I am create a new folder and place the .rpm file under it. then running `createrepo -v /path/to/rpm` and then run it. It works fine. When I move it to S3 I have issues with `Package does not match intended download` errors

Answer (score 0):

Hashed key of packages after downloading might not match with repository. Retry executing update after clearing metadata.

```
# yum clean all ; yum update
```